# Determine if the NavigationDrawer is opening or closing

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Is there any way for me to determine whether the navigation drawer is opening or closing? I have read about `isDrawerOpen()` and `isDrawerVisible()` methods, but they only return true if the navigation drawer is opened or is visible respectively.

I also read about `onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)` method which gets called when the drawer is moving. The `slideOffset` is the floating value between 0 and 1 telling which position the drawer is at now. But even that gets called when the drawer is opening **and** closing.

What I need to do is, to do something only when the drawer is opening but not when closing, something tells me that I have to use `onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)` method, but I just can't figure out how to check if it is opening and is not closing.

Thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To track the last value is an option ...

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerListener() {

        private float last = 0;

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View arg0, float arg1) {

            boolean opening = arg1>last;
            boolean closing = arg1<last;

            if(opening) {
                Log.i("Drawer","opening");
            } else if(closing) {
                Log.i("Drawer","closing");
            } else {
                Log.i("Drawer","doing nothing");
            }

            last = arg1;
        }

        @Override public void onDrawerStateChanged(int arg0) {}
        @Override public void onDrawerOpened(View arg0) {}
        @Override public void onDrawerClosed(View arg0) {}

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are using `ActionBar` ovveride `ActionBarDrawerToggle`

Further reading: 
[Listen for Open and Close Events on developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#OpenClose)

Answer (score 0):

The [setDrawerListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout) method is now [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639454/method-setdrawerlistener-is-deprecated). The new way to do this is to use the addDrawerListener method.

**In Kotlin**:

1. Initialize the [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout) View

   `val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)`
2. In your main activity, create an inner class that is a subclass of [DrawerLayout.DrawerListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639454/method-setdrawerlistener-is-deprecated). The DrawerLayout class implements the DrawerListener interface. You can track the changing drawer position in onDrawerSlide (Kotlin-ized version of answer above):

   ```
   inner class CustomDrawer : DrawerLayout.DrawerListener{
     override fun onDrawerStateChanged(newState: Int) {
     }

   var last: Float = 0f

   override fun onDrawerSlide(drawerView: View, slideOffset: Float) {
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(drawerView?.getWindowToken(), 0)

       var opening: Boolean = slideOffset>last
       var closing: Boolean = slideOffset<last

       if(opening) {
           Log.i("Drawer","opening")
           Log.d("Last",last.toString())
       } else if(closing) {
           Log.i("Drawer","closing")
           Log.d("Last",last.toString())
       } else {
           Log.i("Drawer","doing nothing")
           Log.d("Last",last.toString())
       }
   }

   override fun onDrawerClosed(drawerView: View) {

     }

   override fun onDrawerOpened(drawerView: View) {

     }
   }
   ```
3. Add your custom DrawerListener to the drawerLayout (I put it in the onCreate method)

   `var drawerListener = CustomDrawer()`
   `drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerListener)`