# Method setDrawerListener is deprecated

Tags: android, drawerlayout, deprecation-warning

While I'm doing something on my app, I see that the navigation drawer on my app reduced its size. But I'm not doing anything on that.

[image: navigation drawer]

Then, after checking the code, I saw that setDrawerListener is deprecated. Does anyone has a solution to this?

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
```

Comment: The deprecated code probably has nothing to do with the drawer size. It means that they will remove support for it in the future (the specific method). It probably is replaced with an addDrawerListener but I'm not sure on that.

Comment: i see.. but i can't see any problem, I just created a new fragment that is not connected on that drawer.. can't really understand why that thing happened...

Comment: what version of library you are using ?

Comment: I'm using this >> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    , compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0', compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'

Answer (score 763, accepted):

Use `addDrawerListener()` instead.

Comment: For API consistency. They added `removeDrawerListener()` so `add...` is named to match

Comment: at least they could included `use 'addDrawerListener' instead` to deprecated message!

Comment: So... can we add multiple drawer listeners?

Answer (score 87):

Replace:

```
drawer.setDrawerListener(...);
```

with

```
drawer.addDrawerListener(...);
```

> `public void setDrawerListener(DrawerLayout.DrawerListener listener)` Sets a listener to be notified of drawer events.
>
> Note that this method is deprecated and you should use `addDrawerListener(DrawerLayout.DrawerListener)` to add a listener and `removeDrawerListener(DrawerLayout.DrawerListener)` to remove a registered listener.

Comment: Where should we remove the drawer listener and is this necessary?

Comment: @portfoliobuilder It depends. Generally, it's not necessary. If you set it in `onCreate()` and you rotate screen whole activity is recreated and new listener is set. More complex cases should be handled with thought that (probably) there is no need to have more than 1 listener set to `DrawerLayout`.

Answer (score 30):

Replace `setDrawerListener`

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
```

with `addDrawerListener`

```
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
```

**example**

```
  DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            assert drawer != null;
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            assert navigationView != null;
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 22):

I guess I'm gonna answer my question. The latest `navigationView` produces its default `android:layout_height` at almost `18dp` when you choose `"wrap_content"`. So, you must choose the `android:layout_height` that you want for your `navigationView` or simply make `android:layout_height="match_parent"`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="550dp"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view_admin"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Anyways, it's height automatically increases when you add an item in the navigation drawer.

Lastly, Use `addDrawerListener()` instead of `setDrawerListener()` as Luxi Liu said.

Comment: because that's not my main question. can't you see? Please read my problem before... It's not only the deprecated thing,

Comment: Then may be fix your question's title

Answer (score 0):

In **Official Android Developer Documents**[image]